# Is it possible to use ado.net in Excel 2002

Tags: .net, excel, excel-2002

I have some stability issue with using ADO and latest sybase driver in Excel 2002.

I just want to find out if there is any alternative.

So is it possible at all to use ADO.net in Excel 2002? Is there any good resources out there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible if you wrap up your logic into COM object and reference it from the VBA code.